# Is it possible to sum values from different rows and them consolidate them into a single row on ms access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm currently making a query for school in which I need to SUM values from different rows which are grouped by a repeated value. How can I sum values and then group those values by costumer?

I've tried a few codes, but can get the syntax of how to make them usable across different rows. Example of what I have and what I want:

```
Customer |  Rentals Jan value
Chris    |     $2,50 
Chris    |     $25,00 
Chris    |     $7,50 
Robert   |     $50,00 
Allan    |     $5,00 
Allan    |     $5,00 
Julia    |     $2,50 
Barbara  |     $2,50 
Barbara  |     $2,50
```

Expected Results:

```
Allan   | $ 10,00 
Barbara | $ 5,00 
Chris   | $ 35,00 
Julia   | $ 2,50 
Robert  | $ 50,00
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Aggregate query. GROUP BY. Query in design view, click the Sigma button on ribbon. Build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs in textboxes. This allows viewing detail data as well as summary calcs.